# How to load customizations for matplotlib graphs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used customization using css and other scripts for matplotlib graphs on ipython notebooks. Can I use the customization scripts for the code being run on terminal? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib allows customizations using so called `rcParams`. The documentation is pretty easily accessible:

http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html